# Inflate a ListView/ExpandableListView from an inflated Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, expandablelistview

To make it a bit more simple let's say I have a service which uses a layoutinflater to inflate a button from a layout. That inflated button gets displayed above all other apps (using **SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW** permission) and looks like this:

[image: button overlay]

Code for starting the service from the main activity:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start Overlay"
        android:id="@+id/btn_start"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn_start;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);

        btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ButtonOverlay.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Code for the service:

**ButtonOverlay.java**

```
public class ButtonOverlay extends Service{

    private WindowManager wm;
    private LinearLayout ll;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        ll = new LinearLayout(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(50, 255, 255, 255));
        ll.setLayoutParams(llParameters);

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams parameters = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        parameters.x = 0;
        parameters.y = 0;
        parameters.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;

        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ll = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.activity_button, null);

        Button btn = (Button) ll.findViewById(R.id.btn_click);
        wm.addView(ll, parameters);
    }
}
```

Layout that contains the inflated button:

**activity_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click"
        android:id="@+id/button_click"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now what I want to do is set up an onClickListener for the button `btn_click`, so that when you tap on it another layout with a listView or better expandableListView is inflated.
Here is what I need with a plain TextView:

[image: floating window]

*But I don't know how to do it with a **listView** or **expandableListView**, since they are more complex.

Am I even going the right way to create overlays like this?

How should I structure my code to keep it clean with multiple overlayed buttons which can inflate different layouts (e.g. `button1` shows plain text like in the picture above, `button2` shows a listview, `button3` shows an imageview)?*

**Edit 1:**

I hab a look at [this example](http://www.journaldev.com/9942/android-expandablelistview-example-tutorial) for an `expandableListView` and to get it working as a standalone project was no problem. I was trying to inflate that exact example as floating window jst like the `plainTextView`, but I don't know where I should put the code within the `onCreate` method. Any ideas?